# Visual Studio 2008 SharePoint WebPart Deploy Problem - "The HTTP request is unauthorized...'Negotiate,NTLM'"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts, vsewss

I am trying develop a SharePoint WebPart with "Visual Studio 2008 Extensions, Version 1.3". 
When I try deploy or quick deploy or package or anything about deployment for my WebPart I am getting this message:

**The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.**

Is there someone who has a solution for this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue myself a while ago.

It's because vsewss 1.3 wants to connect to SharePoint to read metadata (it's being smart....)

Google was my friend, it'll be yours too.... ;)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/992297a5-208e-429e-9488-2cd6725ed953

Answer (score 0):

A common cause fo Negotiate failure is unsynchronised clocks on the machines concerned.  Negotiate uses Kerberos which requires the parties involved has system clocks set with-in 5 minutes of each other.

Ordinarily this isn't a problem in an AD forest since by default time cascades from the PDC in the root domain. However I've seen this broken quite a few times at various clients.